# TabLayout OnTabSelectedListener not working inside DialogFragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

Last two days I am unable to fix this problem. I have implemented `DialogFragment` with two tabs and viewpager, swipe is working proper but `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` is not working. Please check below code snippet which I have done.

**CheckOutDialogFragment Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkout_discount_header"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:tabBackground="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/jio_main_color"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/jio_main_color"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/BillingTabStyle"
        app:tabTextColor="#FF8C8C8C"  />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:background="@color/greytext" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp271"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code for BaseDialogFragment**

```
public abstract class BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    /*Properties*/
    @Nullable
    private BaseActivity mActivity;
    /*Life-cycle methods*/

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof BaseActivity) {
            BaseActivity mActivity = (BaseActivity) context;
            this.mActivity = mActivity;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mActivity = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Nullable
    public BaseActivity getBaseActivity() {
        return mActivity;
    }

    protected abstract void setUp(View view);

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*the content*/
        final RelativeLayout root = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        root.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        /*creating the fullscreen dialog*/
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(root);
        if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
            ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        }
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        DisplayMetrics discountDisplaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();        
        mActivity.getWindowManager()
        .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(discountDisplaymetrics);
        int w = discountDisplaymetrics.widthPixels;
        if (!(dialog.isShowing())) {
            dialog.show();
        }
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(w, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        return dialog;
     }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setUp(view);
    }

    /*Dialog fragment show method*/
    public void show(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, String tag) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment prevFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (prevFragment != null) {
            transaction.remove(prevFragment);
        }
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        show(transaction, tag);
    }

@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**Code for CheckoutDiscountDialogFragment.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.jio.bapp.R;
import com.jio.bapp.checkout.model.CheckoutCartData;
import com.jio.bapp.checkout.util.CheckoutCalculation;
import com.jio.bapp.retailpos.billing.adapter.StartBillingTabPageAdapter;
import com.jio.bapp.view.HelveticaNeueRegularTextView;

public class CheckoutDiscountDialogFragment extends BaseDialogFragment{
    /*Properties*/

    public TabLayout mTablayout;
    ViewPager mViewpager;

    private View view;

    /*Important method to get call for this fragment.*/

    @NonNull
    public static CheckoutDiscountDialogFragment newInstance(int type) {
        CheckoutDiscountDialogFragment fragment = new CheckoutDiscountDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(BUNDLE_TYPE, type);        
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    /*Fragment life-cycle method*/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            mType = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("type") : 1;

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mType = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_TYPE) : 1;               
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkout_discount_dialog, container, false);
        res = this.getResources();
        mTablayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        mViewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


        mTablayout.addTab(mTablayout.newTab().setText("Amount"));
        mTablayout.addTab(mTablayout.newTab().setText("Discount"));
        mTablayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Amount"));
        mTablayout.getTabAt(1).setText("Discount"));

        //**********Adding divider between tabs*********
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) mTablayout.getChildAt(0);
        linearLayout.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.search_layout_border));//;Color(Color.GRAY);
        drawable.setSize(3, 3);
        drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#E8E8E8"));
        linearLayout.setDividerPadding(20);
        linearLayout.setDividerDrawable(drawable);
        ChoDiscountTabFragmentAdapter adapter = new ChoDiscountTabFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mTablayout.getTabCount());
        mViewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
        /*If Uncomment this below line tab Title gets invisible. */
        //mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);
        mViewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTablayout));
        /*tried below two lines still its not working.*/
        //mTablayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(tabSelectedListener(mViewpager));
        //mTablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(tabSelectedListener(mViewpager));
        mTablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener);
        /*Tried below but not working.*/
        /* mTablayout.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (mTablayout.getTabAt(0).equals(getResources().getString(R.string.checkout_amount_discount_tab))) {

                    mViewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tab 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    mViewpager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tab 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });*/

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mViewpager.invalidate();
        return view;
    }
    private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener tabSelectedListener(final  ViewPager pager)
    {
        return  new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tab 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        };
    }
    public void show(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String tag) {
        super.show(fragmentManager, tag);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @NonNull
    private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    };
}
```

**Code for ChoDiscountTabFragmentAdapter**

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.jio.bapp.checkout.model.CheckoutCartData;
import com.jio.bapp.retailpos.billing.activity.LooseProductFragment;
import com.jio.bapp.retailpos.billing.activity.ScanProductFragment;
import com.jio.bapp.retailpos.billing.activity.StartBillingActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChoDiscountTabFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int mNumOfTabs;
    private final CheckoutDiscountDialogFragment mContext;
    private Fragment mCurrentFragment;

    public ChoDiscountTabFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;      
        this.mContext = mContext;      
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                CheckOutDiscountFragment amountFragment = CheckOutDiscountFragment.newInstance(0);
                amountFragment.setCartData(updateAmountToCollectListener);
                return amountFragment;
            case 1:
                CheckOutPercentageFragment percentageFragment = CheckOutPercentageFragment.newInstance(1);
                percentageFragment.setCartData(updatePercentageToCollectListener);
                return percentageFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return  mNumOfTabs;
    }
    public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
        return mCurrentFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        if (getCurrentFragment() != object) {
            try {
                if (null != mContext && null != mContext.mTablayout) {
                    mContext.mTablayout.setScrollPosition(position, 0f, true);
                }
                mCurrentFragment = ((Fragment) object);
                if (object instanceof CheckOutDiscountFragment) {
                    CheckOutDiscountFragment f = (CheckOutDiscountFragment) object;
                    if (f != null) {
                        f.getCartData(cartDataIs.getCartId());
                    }
                }else if(object instanceof CheckOutPercentageFragment) {
                    CheckOutPercentageFragment f = (CheckOutPercentageFragment) object;
                    if (f != null) {
                        f.getCartData(cartDataIs.getCartId());
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    }
}
```

**Code for CheckOutDiscountFragment**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.jio.bapp.R;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.Unbinder;

public class CheckOutDiscountFragment extends Fragment {
    /*Properties*/
    public static final String BUNDLE_TYPE = "type";
    private View rootView;
    public int mType;
    private Unbinder unbinder;
    private Resources res;
    public CheckOutDiscountFragment() {
    }

    /* Creational */
    @NonNull
    public static CheckOutDiscountFragment newInstance(int type) {
        CheckOutDiscountFragment fragment = new CheckOutDiscountFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(BUNDLE_TYPE, type);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            mType = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("type") : 0;

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mType = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getInt("type") : 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkout_discount_amount_fragment, container, false);
        res = this.getResources();unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            this.mListener = (updateDiscount) context; /*Activity communicator (Fragment - to - Activity)*/
        } catch (@NonNull final ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement Listener");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me to fix this problem, suggest me if I am doing wrong in `DialogFragment` code.

Comment: If the only problem with `setupWithViewPager()` was the missing tab text, you just need to override the `getPageTitle()` in `ChoDiscountTabFragmentAdapter`. Did everything else work with that? Also, in your layout, you should add an appropriate `layout_below` on the `ViewPager`. The `layout_behavior` attribute does nothing in a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM. I am not adding fragment using **addFragment** method so how I can get the fragmentList through which I can get title according to possion.

Comment: You already know the titles for both positions, yeah? So something like `if (position == 0) { return "Amount"; }`, etc.

Comment: @MikeM, Thank you so much for suggestion, I did changes as you said and now it is working as expected.